# FileInputStream java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java

I should preface that this code is being run in IBM JDK 7. The following line of code throws a FileNotFound exception.

```
properties.load(new FileInputStream("/myApp/properties/props.properties"));
```

The same line of code works fine on my colleagues computers though. For some reason on their machines there is an implicit `C:` that is assumed in front of that path, which is what I need to happen on my computer. We have put our heads together but haven't figured out a solution to the problem.

When I run this line

```
properties.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\myApp\\properties\\props.properties"));
```

It works fine and does not throw an error. As you can see I have specifically put the `C:` in the path. How can I get the first line of code to assume there is an implicit `C:` ?

Comment: Are you saying that on your colleagues Windows machine, the line `new FileInputStream("/myApp/properties/props.properties")` actually loads the file `C:\myApp\properties\props.properties`? This would be _very_ weird.

Comment: You should be using `getResourceAsStream()` instead of absolute paths like that.

Comment: How do you start your program? is the current working directory on drive C?

Comment: the first statement contains a relative path. The second is absolute. Check mich is your current directory (new File().getAbsolutePath()) and set the path relative to this location.

Comment: @Tunaki Yes that's what I'm saying

Comment: If you assume the file is located at the `C:` drive in unrelated to the project folder, then you must specified it as such. The preferred solution would be to use relative to your project location.

Comment: @Henry No, the current working directory is not on the C drive. That could actually be the problem.

Comment: @Henry that was the problem. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Graham You can get the current drive from the system environment  `System.getenv("SystemDrive");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows the file name `/myApp/properties/props.properties` is not absolute as it does not specifiy a drive letter. The OS will add the drive of the current working directory to make it an absolute file name.

So if the program is started with the current working directory on drive C all is fine, if started from another drive the file will not be found.